# no match for 'operator[]' error for some reason

Tags: c++

I have this object with a vectors of pointers. I am trying to access a pointer but I just can't for some reason

> myNode.cpp:83: error: no match for 'operator[]' in    '((MyProjectGraph::MyNode*)this)->MyProjectGraph::MyNode::out[i]'
>
> myNode.cpp:88: error: no match for 'operator[]' in '((MyProjectGraph::MyNode*)this)->MyProjectGraph::MyNode::in[i]'

```
/** Bannana
 * bannana
 **/ 
void MyNode::toString( ){
    cout<<"Name: "<<ltr<<"\nValue: "<<value<<"\nTime: "<<time<<endl;
        
    cout<<"\n Outgoing To: "<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < out.size(); i++){
        cout<<(out[i]->in->ltr)<<endl; //L 85
    }
        
    cout<<" Incoming To: "<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++){
        cout<<((in[i]->out)->ltr)<<endl; // L 88
    }
}
```

Node class fields

```
std::list<MyEdge*> in;
std::list<MyEdge*> out;
```

Edge class fields

```
MyNode* in;
MyNode* out;
```

Comment: operator[] is not defined in std::list, if you want to use it, use std::vector instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::list` doesn't support the array indexing operation. You can iterate over the items of a `std::list` using `std::list::iterator` or a *range-for* statement.

For pre-C++11, use:

```
std::list<MyEdge*>::iterator iter = out.begin();
std::list<MyEdge*>::iterator end = out.end();
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter )
{
   cout << (*iter)->in->ltr << endl;
}
```

For C++11 or later, use:

```
for ( autu& item : out )
{
   cout << item->in->ltr << endl;
}
```

Make similar changes to iterate over the items of `in`.